# Propagate entries manually between sites

Tags: localization, multi-site

I have a client that wants to setup a multilingual site, but for the purpose of this site they only want certain entries to be translated.

If I setup sites that use a section which is configured to NOT propagate entries across sites, then I haven't found a way to link entries manually for entries that I DO want to propagate. Is this not possible? One could of course just create the entries manually, but then I loose the linking between them to provide a language switcher though. Also, I can't really re-save an entry on another site easily.

Is the preferred approach to do propagate and keep them unpublished? I feel that that makes it unwieldy very quickly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think one solution is new propagation method 'Let each entry choose which sites it should be saved to', introduced in Craft 3.5.

see [this issue](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/5988#issuecomment-622473302) for more information.

Comment: Oh, very nice, I had missed that. I guess I have to take a stab at that upgrade that keeps failing then https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/36061/upgrading-craft-cms-fails